# Auto sync iPhone video with MacBook

Tags: ios, mac, video, data-synchronization

I take videos with my iPhone and I would like them to be automatically transferred to my MacBook without using iCloud.

The use case is that I take large videos, filming for 15 min to hours and I want the files to get to my computer as soon as the camera is stopped. Because those files are larges they fill the phone fast and it’s annoying to always have to stop, plug the phone, select the files, delete the files, etc.

I would like to set it up once and have the file transferred via WiFi and deleted on the iPhone as soon as the video is taken and the WiFi is on.

With all the people vlogging, there should be a better way.

I tried Airdrop and I had a look at software to sync (like Syncthing) but it seems that iOS forbids automatic actions on files so it’s not possible for a third-party application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned,

> it seems that iOS forbids automatic actions on files

That is true, for both third party, and as far as I know, for first party too. By that I mean there is no native ways in iOS and macOS to use your MacBook as a storage medium for your iPhone to immediately dump recorded videos into it over WiFi automatically upon finishing a recording.

Since firstly this sort of needs is very niche and Apple would highly likely to not bother adding such feature anytime soon (I may be wrong).

Secondly, videos you record has to go through several steps before it is ready to be used. When you stop the camera, the recorded footage needs to be encoded into device readable format. Then it takes time to transfer data whether wired or wirelessly to other devices.

> I want the files to get to my computer as soon as the camera is stopped

Hence achieving this is not very realistic.

However doing the same thing, but with photos is possible, thanks to Continuity Camera. Here's a summary of how to do it, but [Official Apple Documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209037) is also available for reference.

To import a captured image from your iPhone immediately onto your Mac, right click your Mac desktop, select "Import from iPhone or iPad", find your iPhone in the list, choose "Take Photo".

Any photos taken by your iPhone in this state will immediately be transferred over onto your Mac's Desktop, automatically.

For your need of transferring videos, I think AirDrop is the simplest and easiest way to go. Of course if you have genuinely large video files (10GB+), a high speed external SSD will come in handy.

If the reason you would like to sync content between devices without iCloud is because you think iCloud is not good enough for you, consider OneDrive. This service also has automatic content synchronization feature between devices. The only caveat I see is that it can take a while for large videos to upload from your phone and be downloaded onto your Mac.